# Moved to new house and found old cabling

Tags: cable

I moved in to a new house and noticed that there are some cables running from 1st to 2nd to 3rd floor. I was wondering whether anyone could help me understand what they might be, I think they might be ISDN but def not a expert here.

Here's a shot of the box with the wires pulled out:

[image]

and here is close up:

[image]

Ideally I want to network the house from bottom to top and wondering whether these cables would be able to help me even if its just to pull at cat6 cable through.

Comment: Likely phone cabling.  It looks like there's a label on the side.  If there's any slack, pull some out and update the Question with the text thereon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are 22AWG or 24AWG solid copper runs for intercoms or telephone extensions and not suited for network use. Use them to pull in [cable pull tape or pull string](https://www.google.com/search?q=cable%20pull%20string), which can then be used to pull in CAT5E or CAT6E wiring for functional networking. A device which puts an audio signal on a pair, along with an speaker with induction pickup (e.g., a [Fox and Hound signal tracer](https://www.google.com/search?q=Fox%20and%20Hound%20signal%20tracer)) would help you quickly identify which goes where.